# Entity Framework SaveChanges doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to save some records into a SQL Server database using EF6 and this code:

```
_db.MyEntity.Add(item);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

I can see the code/stored procedure in SQL Server Profiler (RPC:Completed) so it's being executed and when I run the same SQL manually in Management Studio, then the insert works OK (item has been inserted without errors).

[image]

Is there a reason why this doesn't work?

Am I missing something (`DbContext` is OK as I have `_db.Remove(item)` few lines above that works fine)?

Comment: check your tables index! same times can't insert is from it.

Comment: Could you please include few more information, would you kindly update th question in a way so that contributor could reproduce or get more insight of the issue.

Comment: "SaveChanges doesn't work", in what way exactly? An exception? Nothing happens? ....?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the issue was caused by data type. SQL identity column was INT and in API model it was LONG.
As I said, I wasn't getting any errors on executions and the sql code copied from sql server profiler worked when executed.

Changing LONG to INT32 in API model resolved this issue for me (insert from API works).